# How to retrieve an url parameter in the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting, parameter-passing

I'am trying to retrieve an parameter passed in a url using the zend framework. But of course, it is not working !
My code looks like this :

Generating the url :

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'poll', 'action' => 'showresults', 'poll_id' => $poll['_id']), null, true) ?>
```

Retrieving the "poll_id" parameter in showresultsAction() :

```
 $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
 $poll_id = $request->getParam('poll_id');
```

The problem is that $poll_id is NULL. When I do a var_dump of $request->getParams(), it is also NULL. I have glanced trough the Zend Framework doc, but it was not very usefull. Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: If you need to get the request object from outside of a controller you can always do Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$poll_id = $request->getParam('poll_id');
```

Try:

```
$request = $this->getRequest(); //$this should refer to a controller
$poll_id = $request->getParam('poll_id');
```

Or:

```
$poll_id = $this->_getParam('poll_id'); //$this should refer to a controller
```

The Zend Framework automagically attaches the request object to a controller.

Comment: Good catch! Thinking about it now, I imagine instantiating it a second time is a bad idea. >.> [thwaps self]

Answer (score 1):

Try to involve this from the controller:

```
$params = $this->params()->fromQuery();
```

It returns all URL parameters.